# Prevent Caching on a specific RTK Query Endpoint

Tags: reactjs, redux, rtk-query

I am using rtq query and i have an endpoint that takes azure-ad oid from the global store and makes a query to the backend to check if the user exists on the backend to check if the user exists. If the user exists then I redirect the user to the dashboard else I do not redirect the user.

The problem is that despite trying to prevent caching on that endpoint, it still uses the cached data and by the time the real data comes from the server, the redirect has already happened. Below are some of the steps I have taken to prevent this from happening.

1. Using refetch
2. Setting refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true,
3. Setting  keepUnusedDataFor: 0.0001 to invalidate the cache almost immediately

The point is that I do not want this endpoint to use any cached data.

Below is my component:

```js
 const [isSignedIn] = useIsSignedIn();
  const history = useHistory();
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const ongraphLogin = async (role: string) => {
    if (Providers.globalProvider.login) {
      dispatch(setloginType(role));

      await Providers.globalProvider.login();
    }
  };
  const userState = useAppSelector(state => state.userState);

 
  console.log(userState?.currentUser?.id);
  const { data, error, isLoading, refetch } = useGetUserByOidQuery(userState?.currentUser?.id, {
    skip: isSignedIn,
    refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true
  });
  
  useEffect(() => {
    refetch();
    // console.log(res);
    if (isSignedIn) {
      console.log('I am in');
      // Check if the user exists in the ndovysystem
      if (data?.status === 'success') {
        console.log(data);
        history.push('/user');
      } else if (userState.loginType === 'volunteerRegistration') {
        history.push('/register/volunteer');
      } else if (userState.loginType === 'menteeRegistration') {
        history.push('/register/mentee');
      }
    }
  }, [isSignedIn, data]);
```

Below is the endpoint

```js
import { ndovuAPI } from './ndovuAPI';

export const ndovuUserAPI = ndovuAPI.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: builder => ({
    getUserByOid: builder.query({
      query: (oid: string) => `/users/oid/${oid}`,
      keepUnusedDataFor: 0.0001
    })
  })
});

// Export hooks for usage in functional components
export const { useGetUserByOidQuery} = ndovuUserAPI;
```

Kindly help me solve this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hmm. You can't really *prevent* caching of queries, but you could make that a mutation - by default even two mutations with the same arguments never share a cache entry.

Comment: I have faced the same issue, If I use mutation I can't use `skip, refetchOnMountOrArgChange, isLoading, isSuccess, etc..` right?

Comment: Is there any other solution for that too?

Comment: @DanielprabhakaranN since the whole point of RTK Query is to cache data, I guess the correct answer would in the end be to just use `fetch` for this. You cannot circumvent core functionality.

Comment: there are use cases where a particular endpoint of an api should bypass the default aggressive caching behavior. Indeed there are other bypasses and possible modifications built into the caching options of RTK Query... potentially this is down to the poor api design of other services, however having a separate fetch implementation for a single route also is non-optimal

Comment: @ßiansorÅ.Ålmerol I have honestly no idea what you are talking about here... Can you make a new question where you ask an actual question and lay down your assumptions? It seems like you are jumping to some conclusion here and I have no idea what thought process brought you there.

Answer (score 12):

You can pass timestamp as an argument of the query. That's what I did to prevent caching on mounting of the component.

Like this

```
const timestampRef = useRef(Date.now()).current;
const {data = [], isFetching} 
    = useGetChatMessagesQuery({id: chatId, lastMessageId, sessionId: timestampRef});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use 2nd argument as `false` in useLazyQuerySubscription or useLazyQuery

```
const [triggerGetUsers, { isLoading, error }] = useLazyGetUsersQuery();
 


const handleGetUsers = async (reqBody) => {

const { data: usersData, isLoading } = await triggerGetUsers(reqBody, false);

};
```

References: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/queries#hook-types

1. useLazyQuery

Returns a tuple with a trigger function, the query result, and last promise info. Similar to useQuery, but with manual control over when the data fetching occurs. **Note: the trigger function takes a second argument of** `preferCacheValue?: boolean` **in the event you want to skip making a request if cached data already exists.**

2. useLazyQuerySubscription

Returns a tuple with a trigger function, and last promise info. Similar to useQuerySubscription, but with manual control over when the data fetching occurs. **Note: the trigger function takes a second argument of** `preferCacheValue?: boolean` **in the event you want to skip making a request if cached data already exists.**

Answer (score 1):

For my case I have a scenario which registers the user in data base the very first time they login with a 3rd party OAuth. But when the said component loads asynchronously which relies on user being in the db, I added a hook with refetch to check if the user is in db at that point.
`const { refetch } = useFetchUserQuery(authUserId);`(useFetchUserQuery is the rtk query endpoint)
`const userInDb =  (await refetch(authUserId).unwrap());`
If user exists all the logged in functionality is made available if not just the default functionality. The refetch hook is dependent on userid and signed in status change. This project is in javascript

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
const { data, isFetching, refetch } = useSkillsListQuery(undefined, {
  refetchOnMountOrArgChange: 3600, // in seconds
});
```

This causes the query to invalidate the cache in 3600secs (1hr) and refetch automatically on component remount.

You can also use `refetch` to manually trigger a refetch which will invalidate the cache.